# Time added to Firestore's Timestamp upon adding a document

Tags: datetime, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have Firestore documents that use `Timestamp`. I've checked every part of my code and I'm 100% sure the `Instant`s I use to create timestamp always contain only dates like `2020-05-01T00:00:00Z`. However, when I look a the https://console.firebase.google.com I see strange things. Each timestamp has suddenly additional time in it. It's either *1:00:00 AM UTC+1* or *2:00:00 AM UTC+2*.

In order to turn `Instant` to `Timestamp` I use this extension:

```
fun Instant.toTimestamp(): Timestamp {
    return Timestamp.ofTimeSecondsAndNanos(this.epochSecond, this.nano)
}
```

How is it possible that correct data on the client side becomes incorrect when saved? What am I missing here?

I use batch updates and I also checked the mutations it contains and everything is fine there too. I converted all its timestamps back to `Instant`s and none of them contained time. Why do they appear in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamps don't encode a timezone - they are always UTC.  However, the Firebase web console displays timestamps using the timezone configuration of the local machine running the browser (for local readability).  If you query for the document and get the timestamp back out, it will be the same as the time you put in (again, internally represented in UTC).

Comment: Indeed! I created a query to get all the documents from firestore and there is no time in the timestamp. I'm relieved. _Only_ a display bug in the console :-(

Comment: It's actually not a bug at all - the console is working as intended.

Comment: Mhmm... I would understand it working as expected when all timestmaps had the same offset but some of them are +1 while others are +2. This seems to be pretty random. Shouldn't there by only one _glitch_?

Comment: As I said, it uses the timezone of the local machine.  If you're seeing something different, contact Firebase support to report it, along with your specific instructions to reproduce the issue.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support